# how to add a library in Xamarin.android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

i just started using xamarin like two days ago, and i am trying to add a library like `implementation "com.example.com:1.0.0"`

> in andriod studio normally you just go to the **build.gradle(module:app)** to add this.

i tried a Xamarin.GradleBindings [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EgorBogatov.XamarinGradleBindings). but it didnt work, when i try to use it,i get an error **m2 repository** not found

Is there anyway i can do this in xamarin.android?

Comment: Binding a Java Library : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/

Comment: Why don't you add the library using Nuget Packages? You are using Xamarin.Android hence coding in csharp, take advantage of existing packages and tools.

Comment: @Woj i have tried this, but the thing is that i want to use my companys private library we use to make how apps

Comment: @SushiHangover so i have to create a binding library for each library i want to use, or i can create many libaries in just one binding library?

Comment: @KayodeIssacAyodele Typically it is one-2-one, one Java library (and any non-public dependancies) to one Xamarin.Android Binding Library project. That is really all that VSIX add-in (Xamarin.GradleBindings) is doing, it is creating a binding library, that you than go to and modify the XPATH-based transforms to help Xamarin add a C# wrapper on top of the Java library.

Comment: @SushiHangover so if i have 10 libaries i have to create 10 binding libaries :(

Comment: @KayodeIssacAyodele Yes, if those Java libraries need to surface their classes to C#/F# so you can instance them from C#/F#  If those Java libraries are consumed by other Java libraries and do not need to be surfaced to C#/F#, then they can be added just to the Xamarin.Android binding library that contains the Java library that will be uses their features. You can create extremely fat binding libraries that contain multiple exposed Java libraries, but I would recommend that you don't do that, editing an XPATH-based transform for one Java library can contain dozens to hundreds of entries.

Comment: @SushiHangover okay i will try using this, but if you find any other way to do this please inform me...thanks

Comment: @KayodeIssacAyodele Start with just one and work through the process... after that maybe you group a couple together, only you can decide it is works for your environment or not (Personally over the course of 6+ years with Xamarin I never do that, it causes more problems then it is worth)

Comment: @SushiHangover 6+ years nice, so how do you add libaries that are not in Nuget Packages?

Comment: @SushiHangover java

Comment: A Xamarin.Android binding library creates a .Net Assembly that contains the Java library, so in the project that consumes this binding library (normally a Xamarin.Android Application project), you just add a "reference" to that project (I'm assuming all of those are within the same solution), so it is "just" a .Net reference (either project based or a hard-coded .Net Assembly `.dll`)

Comment: @SushiHangover i just found another issue :(  the company library is like this `com.example:walkinglib:1.0.0` so i get namespace cannot directly contain members  such as field and methods

Comment: @KayodeIssacAyodele Java does not always map to C# directly, they are different languages   You handle this via transforms : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/customizing-bindings/index

Comment: @KayodeIssacAyodele Also another good resource: https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/dda6d8ace7d071b0e8cb